# How to use the wicked-good-xpath in Selenium WebDriver with C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, wicked-good-xpath

I found the [wicked-good-xpath](https://code.google.com/p/wicked-good-xpath/) that can work with Selenium. It could find XPath faster.

But I don't know how to use it in Selenium WebDriver with C#?

Could you give me some sample code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was under the impression that Selenium uses it in the backend anyway? So why do you need it? You'd gain nothing by explicitly using it.

Comment: It does already use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium already uses it in the IEDriver:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/cpp/IEDriverServer/CHANGELOG  (See version v2.26.0.1)

An XPath library is only used as a fall back when the browser doesn't have a native XPath implementation (I'm pretty sure IE is the only one that doesn't have a native implementation).

A native implementation will always be the fastest.